# scrolling vim above script - how to achieve this

Tags: vim

The two machines I use don't treat vim scrolling the same way. When I'm using vim on my laptop, I can scroll up only to the top of the script; logical, but it prefer the behavior on the machine I use remotely, which allows scrolling to go 'above' the script, and into the shell screen ... this is very useful e.g. for seeing error reports from running the script, for example.

Can anyone tell me how to set up my laptop vim to behave in the same way? I'm running ubuntu 10.04.

```
:version VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr 16 2010
12:33:18) Including patches: 1-330
```

Comment: Terminal information would help.  Stuff like `echo $TERM`, `tput smcup | xxd` (terminal) and `:set t_ti?` (vim)

Comment: @ruakh; thanks, I just noticed someone else had also suggested this. Is there an 'accept' button?

Comment: @ephemient; tput smcup | xxd is 0000000: 1b5b 3f31 3034 3968         .[?1049h; entering :set t_ti yielded t_ti=^[[?1049h; does that help? I don't seem to have a vimrc file, is that the problem (I'm very new to this stuff, thanks for your help)

Comment: Hmm, I should have asked about `:echo &term`, but that's probably correctly `xterm`.  `tput rmcup`/`:set t_te?`, `tput smkx`/`:set t_ks?`, and `tput rmkx`/`:set t_ke?` probably all match too.  Okay, how about this: any differences at all in `:set termcap` between the two machines?  Same terminal emulator?  Any ssh/tmux/screen/etc. in there?

Comment: @ephemient There's a lot to compare with :set termcap! Can you recommend a way to do this? I connect to the remote desktop and then use putty to log onto the remote machine; ps aux shows an sshd running for my login. thanks for helping with this ...

Comment: @ephemient Sorry I don't understand these tput commands, they're not in man tput when I search e.g. /rmcup. What's this beginner missing?!

Comment: They're in `man 5 terminfo`.  So how are you getting to `vim` on the two machines?  Is it by using the PuTTY terminal emulator + ssh client for both?

Comment: I use vim on my laptop directly i.e. open a console, type vim

Comment: Ah, so that's the difference -- locally, Vim is able to switch to alternate screen mode and trap mouse events, but it's not working remotely.  If you prefer the remote behavior, you could try using `ssh` to localhost before Vim.

Answer (score 0):

This is not vim scrolling. Vim will never scroll into a (alternate) terminal.

What happens is, in fact the mouse integration on your remote 'machine' (terminal) isn't working! That's why the scroll action gets handled by the terminal emulator (xterm, Putty, mintty etc.)

You might be able to get that behaviour by setting

```
:se mouse=
```

Or look at `:he mouse` for more information

Comment: Neither of the installations seem to have help installed )-: